# Cannot connect to my local server in Minecraft Bedrock LAN Games on PS4

Tags: minecraft-bedrock-edition, ps4, playstation-plus, minecraft-bedrock-edition-server

I have a Minecraft Bedrock server up and running on my LAN (local network).

In Minecraft on PS4 there is a Friends tab with LAN Games section, where my server appears.

When I click to join the server the advert of PS+ appears.

I don’t want to use online gaming features of Minecraft such as Featured servers, I only wish to play my own server located in my home.

Is there a workaround to this problem?

Answer (score 1):

The workaround for this problem is to use RemotePlay.

Use RemotePlay app on any device that supports it, connect to your PS4, launch Minecraft (restart it if it is running already), connect to your server via friends tab then you can safely swap to the console.

It will work even if you leave the server or put console to sleep.

UPDATE:

So the 1.14.210 seems to break this workaround :(